# Comedy movie, alien report on human sexuality

Tags: identify-this-movie

It is over 20 years since I saw this so please forgive my lack of detail in the memory.

The movie was based on a alien civilizations report on human sexuality.

It followed the developing relationship of a young couple and the comedy came from the alien misinterpretation of their actions.

One sequence I do remember is them going away for the weekend, their inability/embarrassment over purchasing condoms and their solution to the problem which was totaly misunderstood by the alien reporter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is likely [***The Mating Habits of the Earthbound Human***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165874/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_26) (1999).

David Hyde Pierce (of Niles Crane /*Frasier* fame) was the "Narrator"

Synopsis:

> An anthropologist from an alien planet provides voice-over commentary for a documentary look at human courtship, mating, and reproduction: "complex, perverse, tragically beautiful: the earthbound human." The commentary gets some of the details comically wrong (explaining the slap on a newborn's back: "they don't like the looks of the child so they beat it"), but gets right the overall idea. We follow Billy and Jenny from their meeting at a club, initial misunderstandings, his losing her phone number, finally connecting, walks on the beach, soulful talks, meeting each other's parents, friends' advice, and the gradual taking of the relationship to new levels.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mating_Habits_of_the_Earthbound_Human)

> Hyde Pierce, acting out the role of an alien (credited as "infinity-cubed" in the opening credits), narrates a courtship in a late 20th-Century American city, presenting findings and opinions as an extraterrestrial nature documentary. The relationship "footage" is played straight, while the voice-over (with its most often wildly inaccurate theories) and elaborate visual metaphors add comedy. Among other themes the film explores the possibility that, whenever describing their interpretations of other species' acts and feelings, humans may get everything wrong.

Comment: That is it, I remember the slap the baby sequence, thanks a lot.